# How can i hash the rows in the table in React (I will save these hashed lines in mongodb)

Tags: reactjs, hash

I need to hash the rows in table. how to hash ?

const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState({});

```
 <Table striped bordered hover >
                    <tbody>
                        {columns.map((row) => (
                            <tr id={unique_id}  >
                                {row.map((col) =>
                                    <td style={{background:'purple'}}>
                                        <span>{col}</span>
                                    </td>
                                )}                                                                       
                                <td>
                                    <Form.Check aria-label="option 1" onChange={(e) => {
                                        setCheck(e.target.checked);
                                            setSelectedRow(selectedRow => ({
                                                ...selectedRow,
                                                [unique_id]: row
                                            }))
                                    }}/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
  </Table>
```

**UPDATE**

this is how i solved the problem.
I used "npm i object-hash" because my return value is an object.

Comment: by hash do you mean using a hash function like sha256?

Comment: i just saw sha256 but yes it could be like bcrypt @MarkosTh09